# S.P.A angular funciona no localhost mais na web não

Tags: javascript, angular

Boa dia Criei uma SPA com angular tá rodando normalmente no localhost na minha maquina, mas coloquei no guithub e não funcionou,
ate ai pensei que é pq o guithub e para paginas estáticas e blablala.
Mas coloquei no webhost e também  não funcionou:
os links:

https://carlos-alexandre-leutz.github.io/MyNewResumeSPA/
https://alexandre-teste-html.000webhostapp.com/
O repositório:
https://github.com/Carlos-Alexandre-Leutz/MyNewResumeSPA

Comment: Já verificou todos os erros que aparecem no console do navegador?

Comment: lol mano, primeira vez que eu mecho com angular, pensei que tinha feito algo erado mais e pq a cdn que eu estou usando não em ssl, diz no console vou testar

Comment: deu certo, funcionou